# How do I insert a random function inside a loop?

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

So... this is a bit hard to explain, but I want to print with Javascript this result:

[image]

- The '*' character has to be random. SO everytime the page loads, there is a new character randomly exposed inside of my loop. Is it possible? Does anyone have an idea how to get there?

I manage to generate a random function with different characters but they are printing in all rows and always in the same place. What do I have to do to make sure that a random character is printed only once and in a random row every time?

**My code:**

```js
const characters = '&%$*';

function generateRandomCode() {
  let result = ""
  let charactersLength = characters.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
  }
  return result
}


let string = "";
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  for (j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
    string += "#";
  }
  string += generateRandomCode();
  generateRandomCode();
  string += "<br>";
}

document.write(string);
```

**This is what my code prints:**

[image]

Comment: Create 3 random integers outside the loop, one for character, one for row, and one for the position to insert characters. Use these integers inside the loop.

Comment: so the random comes only once in a loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like below. I created 3 random integers outside the loop, one for character, one for row, and one for the position to insert characters. Use these integers inside the loop

```js
const characters = '&%$*';

let string = "";
let rand = generateRandomCode(); // generate an array of 3 random numbers.

console.log(rand);

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    string += rand[1] === i && rand[2] === j ? characters[rand[0]] : "#";
  }

  string += "<br>";
}

function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) { // min and max included 
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}

function generateRandomCode() {
  return [randomIntFromInterval(0, 3), randomIntFromInterval(0, 4), randomIntFromInterval(0, 4)]
}

document.write(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't specifically say that the code is restricted to a loop only, just that you want to create that particular output and that it needs to be changed on every load (at least how I read it)

So if you are free not using a loop, you could also try this option :)

- It generates the array first with all '#' chars
- It picks out a random row, col and character and sets it
- and then prints it to html

```js
const characters = '&$*';
const size = 5;
// create an array with all entries
const set = new Array(size).fill().map( _ => new Array(size).fill('#') );

// choose the row based on the size of the array
const row = Math.floor( Math.random() * set.length );
// choose a column based on the size of the row selected
const col = Math.floor( Math.random() * set[row].length );
// choose a character based on the size of the string
const char = Math.floor( Math.random() * characters.length );

// overwrite the pre-existing # with the random char
set[row][col] = characters[char];

// map the rows to a string and join everything with <br />
document.querySelector('#container').innerHTML = set.map( row => row.join('') ).join('<br />');
```

```css
#container {
  font-family: 'Courier New';
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```